Very low volume of presets in subtractive software synths
I am currently starting using software synthesizers on Linux (Ubuntu 24.04) with my Novation Launchkey MK3 keyboard. While I am trying out various synthesizers, I noticed that some of their presets are almost inaudible. For example, in the preset library "LinnStrument MPE" of Surge XT the Drawbar Organ 1 is inaudible, while the volume of other presets is OK with the same sound settings (in a demo video, the volume of the drawbar organ is actually very audible). As a counter measure, I tried to increase the global volume and the scene volume, but this doesn't bring the volume anything near a satisfactory level. I noticed a similar pattern in other synths.
From my understanding, these synths are subtractive, that means a sound source provides a basic waveform and by subtracting certain frequencies, this waveform is re-shaped into a more complex form to get a more interesting sound. So, my theory is that these presets just subtract too much, so that the sound gets inaudible?
Is this a general issue or is it my system's problem? How can I increase the volume of this sound without having to always tweak my sound settings every time I switch presets/instruments?

Surge XT is not subtractive, it’s hybrid, just like it says. Being hybrid, it probably has some components of subtractive synthesis, but there’s no reason to expect any preset uses subtractive components in it.

Edit: I realize, this particular preset was made for LinnStrument, that is a MPE controller. I can't actually tell you much about these controllers, but it's apparent from the linked video, that the performer can control additional parameters of a synthesizer with slight movements of fingers.
I suspect that this preset is quiet, because it has lots of headroom to be filled by changing some parameter. It is a guess from my side, but I found that increasing the "Phase" parameter changes the timbre similarly to what I hear in the video, and also increases the volume by a lot. Maybe you can try to set this parameter to a different value, or even better, to assign it to some controller, e.g. mod-wheel, so that you can change it while playing?

I found this link with information about integration of Linnstrument with Surge XT.

If you still want to simply adjust the volume, I found you can add a flat EQ with a boost in the "output" channel. It provides up to +48 dB boost, which should be more than enough.


Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it later. Are there more ways to achieve a loudness increase? What's a reasonable level to target for audio production?

@Green绿色 I'm sorry, I installed Surge XT for the first time in order to answer this question, and I don't know. Not sure about recommended level, I would aim for not too quiet, but without going over 0dB. It may depend on your workflow too, e.g. performing live, when you really want to have all presets at compatible volume vs recording in DAW, which gives you more flexibility.

@Green绿色 please see updated answer.
